# How to setup a Backdoor Access within UVM RAL model?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I'm trying to understand Backdoor Access within UVM RAL mode example https://www.edaplayground.com/x/jy3U .

In uvm_guide, it wrote that if HDL paths are used, the root HDL paths must be specified in the environment that instantiates the register model.

I implemented `reg_model.set_hdl_path_root("tb_top.DUT");` in env.sv
and `control_reg.configure(this, null,"control_reg");` in reg_pkg.sv

Then I implemented it to test Backdoor access in base_seq.sv.

```
//TO BACKDOOR ACCESS
    `uvm_info(get_type_name(), "BACKDOOR ACCESS START", UVM_LOW);
    reg_model.mod_reg.control_reg.write(status, 32'h9876_5432, UVM_BACKDOOR, .parent(this));
    reg_model.mod_reg.control_reg.read(status, read_data, UVM_BACKDOOR, .parent(this));
    `uvm_info(get_type_name(), "BACKDOOR ACCESS FINISH", UVM_LOW);
```

I didn't get any Backdoor operation message between `BACKDOOR ACCESS START` and `BACKDOOR ACCESS FINISH`.

Could you guide me how I can setup the Backdoor access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see more messages, you need to change the verbosity setting.  When you don't explcitly set the verbosity, `UVM_MEDIUM` is used.  On edaplayground, change `Run options` from:

```
-access +rw
```

to:

```
-access +rw +UVM_VERBOSITY=UVM_HIGH
```

This is what I see when I run it:

```
UVM_INFO base_seq.sv(35) @ 14: uvm_test_top.env_o.agt.seqr@@rseq [reg_seq] BACKDOOR ACCESS START
UVM_INFO @ 14: reporter [RegModel] Wrote register via DPI backdoor: reg_model.mod_reg.control_reg=0x12341232
UVM_INFO @ 14: reporter [RegModel] Read  register via DPI backdoor: reg_model.mod_reg.control_reg=12341232
UVM_INFO base_seq.sv(38) @ 14: uvm_test_top.env_o.agt.seqr@@rseq [reg_seq] BACKDOOR ACCESS FINISH
```

You can also use `UVM_FULL` or `UVM_DEBUG`.